# Accessing variable from another class

Tags: java, swing, class, variables, jpanel

I am just a newbie in Java. I have this following code snippets:

```
class Canvas extends JPanel{
    int x=-10,y=-10,z=-10;
    public Canvas() {
    }
    public void setCoordinates(int x,int y, int z){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.z=z;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for(int i=0; i<50 ;i++){
            if(p[i].z==1) g.setColor(Color.red);
            else if (p[i].z==2) g.setColor(Color.green);
            else g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillArc(p[i].x-5,p[i].y-5,10,10,0,360);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this class, it's a separate class from the one where `p` belongs.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{
      ......
      public static Points[] p = new Points[50];
      ....
}
```

How can I call the points I have in the class `Frame` so that I can use it in the class Canvas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as `p` is public static you can access it by `Frame.p`, but this is not nice and elegant way

if you want to do this properly, you will create separate object which holds all your points,
you can make it singleton if you want have only one instance. If you create it when your application is created you can pass it to each frame which is using it, or just use static method to access it(will work if you have singleton)

Answer (score 1):

If you declare in this way:

public static `Points[] p = new Points[50];`

you can do: `Frame.p` beacuse `p` **is static**

Instead if you declare `private Points[] p = new Points[50];`
you use a **getter method in Frame class**:

```
public Point[] getPoints() {
    return this.p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Frame.p`, as it is `static` and its name is `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `p` is a public static field of `Frame` class, you can access it with class name like `Frame.p`

Answer (score 0):

you can access it directly `Frame.p` as the field is public static

Answer (score 0):

You can use `public` and `static` fields of one class in other class with its class-name.

Since in your class `Frame` the field `p` is `public static`, so You can use field `p` as `Frame.p` in class `Canves`.

More about static fields : [Static fields](http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/staticfields.htm)